# Python lxml Subelement with text value?

Tags: python, lxml

Is it possible to somehow create element with default text value? So I would not need to do it like this?

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element('root')
a = etree.SubElement(root, 'a')
a.text = 'some text' # Avoid this extra step?
```

I mean you can specify attributes in SubElement, but I don't see a way to specify text in it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there is a builtin way to do that, but if you find yourself doing that many times, it may be better to write a function that encapsulates creating the sub element and setting the text. Example -

```
def create_SubElement(_parent,_tag,attrib={},_text=None,nsmap=None,**_extra):
    result = etree.SubElement(_parent,_tag,attrib,nsmap,**_extra)
    result.text = _text
    return result
```

And then create your element as -

```
a = create_SubElement(root,'a',_text="Some text")
```

Please note, with this you would not be able to create attribute with name `_text` using keyword arguments, you would need to use `attrib` keyword argument for that.

Comment: Hm, I thought this was a solution, but trying it I get this error: `global name 'text' is not defined`

Comment: Oh, I think it was a typo in your code. it should bee `result.text = _text`

Comment: What's with those leading underscores for some of the arguments and why are you ignoring the arguments `attrib` and `nsmap`?

Comment: @BlackJack Sorry, i wrongly copied that from the `help(etree.SubElement)` . I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 15):

How about the following?

```
etree.SubElement(root, "a").text = "some text"
```

Works only if you do not need to assign the resultant element to a variable.

Comment: As matter of fact, I do need to assign to variable, because it is used as parent for another elements

Comment: would be ideal if `.text` returned self, but alas not, probs for he best.