# lxml: adding multiple mixed content (text + elements) child nodes to a parent element

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

Working with `lxml.etree`, I'm trying to build an XML document where some of the elements may have the form:

```xml
<foo>
  There is some text here
  <bar>and then a nested child element</bar>
  And then some more text
</foo>
```

I don't know how many child nodes there are and which of them will be a text node vs. an element. This is built by iterating over an input list and based on the type of each item in the list, deciding whether I want to append a text node or an element.

For example:

```py
parent = etree.Element('foo')
for item in input_data:
    if isinstance(item, str): 
       # Append a text node (???)
       pass
    else:
       parent.append(etree.Element(item['type'], item['text']))
```

Obviously setting `.text` will not do as I want mixed content. I understand that `lxml.etree` doesn't have a "text node element" that I can just append, and that I can use `.tail` to attach text to the last child element. However using `.tail` for this seems very cumbersome, as I would have to keep track of the last element, and check if I need to call `append()` to add a new element or `.text` to set the 1st text child node or use `.tail` on the last item to set some text after it.

Is there a cleaner way of appending mixed content to a parent element in `lxml`?

Comment: Look at using `SubElement()` - e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33386943/python-lxml-subelement-with-text-value and see the ElementTree documentation under the heading Building XML Documents  https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: Maybe you can try another library:)

Comment: @barny you've basically pointed me to the documentation which I've read, but I don't understand how your references answer *my question*. I know how to add subelements, but this API does not support adding text nodes.

Comment: @dabingsou maybe you can point me to a different Python XML library that offers a better API for my use case :)

Comment: It’s a _comment_ - it doesn’t attempt to answer your question.

Comment: @shevron Martin Honnen's answer looks good:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use the builder API with e.g.

```
from lxml import etree as ET
from lxml.builder import E

foo = E.foo(*[item if isinstance(item, str) else E(item['type'], item['text']) for item in ['There is some text here', { 'type' : 'bar', 'text' : 'and then a nested child element'}, 'And then some more text']])
```

Then `ET.tostring(foo)` gives: `b'<foo>There is some text here<bar>and then a nested child element</bar>And then some more text</foo>'`.

Of course given your `input_data` the construction of `foo` would simply read

```
foo = E.foo(*[item if isinstance(item, str) else E(item['type'], item['text']) for item in input_data])
```